# \r in lua it's possible?

Tags: lua, scanning

How do \r in lua ?
This my code :

```
for port = 1, 65535 do
    local sock = socket.tcp()
    local scan = sock:connect("192.168.88.1", port)

    sock:close()

    if scan then
        print("[\27[1m\27[91m+\27[0m] " .. port .. "")
        print("Scanning...\r")

    end
end
```

and the result:

```
[+] 21
Scanning...
[+] 22
Scanning...
[+] 23
Scanning...
[+] 53
Scanning...
[+] 80
Scanning...
[+] 2000
Scanning...
[+] 8291
Scanning...
[+] 8728
Scanning...
[+] 8729
Scanning...
```

and I want that as soon as a port is displayed the `scanning...` is erased and reappears at the end so just after the port.

I can't find much documentation on lua, sorry

i try all the print(en="\r") but it's not fine.

Answer (score 3):

`print` automatically appends a *newline* character (`\n`), which you don't want. Instead, you should use `io.write`. This will however not flush, so you'll have to also use `io.flush`. Here's a simple example using the Unix `sleep` command to wait 1s between messages:

```lua
for i = 1, 10 do
    io.write(("test %02d\r"):format(i))
    io.flush()
    os.execute("sleep 1")
end
```

This will continously overwrite `test XX` with the new value of `i` until `i=10` is reached.